# ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT fail postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query, errors

```
INSERT INTO O_USER (ID, NAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWD, DATE_REG, DATE_UPD, DATE_DEL, IS_DELETE, TIPO, FTP) 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,DEFAULT,NULL,NULL,%s,%s,%s) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT ux DO NOTHING;
```

ux constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux ON public.o_user USING btree (email,username);
```

but in multiple insert have this error:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "o_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(jferraro) already exists.
```

what is the problem?

update add table information:

```
CREATE TABLE O_USER (
    ID          INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME    VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    EMAIL       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    USERNAME    VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PASSWD      VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    DATE_REG    DATE            DEFAULT NOW(),
    DATE_UPD    DATE,
    DATE_DEL    DATE,
    IS_DELETE   NUMERIC         NOT NULL,
    TIPO        VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
    FTP         VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  DEL             CHECK       (IS_DELETE IN ('0','1')),
    CONSTRAINT  FK_FTP          FOREIGN KEY (FTP) REFERENCES FTP_USERS(FTP_USER),
    CONSTRAINT  UX              UNIQUE      (EMAIL,USERNAME),
    CONSTRAINT  TYP             CHECK       (TIPO IN ('ADMIN','STANDARD'))
);
```

update resolve the problem:
the problem was that i declared two different mode for make unique email and username, for resolve this problem i delete unique near the collums and use only unique constraint "UX" for email and username.
thanks all for the support.

Comment: You have another constraint named `o_user_username_key` which is violated.

Comment: Try `\d o_*` (or is it `\dt o_*`) from the psql client! +1 for a decent first question. p.s. welcome to the forum ;-)

Comment: i haven't other constraint called equal.
The problems are 'UNIQUE' near collum and in constraint?
i add the constraint after, because the 'ON CONFLICT' can't take multiple collums, and think make a constraint for make my life easier.
thanks for rep :)

Comment: You have a primary key on `id` - that's also a unique constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
EMAIL       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
USERNAME    VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

makes both `EMAIL` and `USERNAME` individually unique, in addition to your other constraint. If only a combination of `EMAIL` and `USERNAME` is to be unique, remove `UNIQUE` from the column definitions.

Comment: thanks, i supposed this, now try and work!